# Outlook 2010 html email vertical 1px space between hyperlinked images

Tags: html, css, html-email, outlook-2010

I have been working on this html for a while trying to figure out why outlook 2010 is adding this 1px white line between images that are hyperlinked.

I am pretty sure I have tried all the tricks I have read about Html emails and outlook. Below is the code/styling I am using for just 2 tables. They have 1 single image in each. If I remove the hyperlink, there is no space in outlook 2010. If I leave the hyperlink I can't find a way to get rid of the space!

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="600">
        <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="600" height="179" >
                <a href="http://www.anzie.com/" style="height: 179px;  width: 600px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  display:block;  float: left; border:0; vertical-align:bottom;"><img border="0" align="left" alt="Gold Rush" height="179" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/ESSETIAL6_FALL_01.jpg" style="height: 179px;  width: 600px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  display:block;  float: left; border:0; vertical-align:bottom;" width="600" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="600">
        <tr>
            <td style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="600" height="25">
                <a href="http://www.anzie.com/viewall_gold.php" style="height: 25px;  width: 600px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  display:block;  float: left; border:0; vertical-align:bottom; border:0;"><img align="left"  border="0" alt="Shop Gold" height="25" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/ESSETIAL6_FALL_02.1.jpg" style="height: 25px;  width: 600px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  display:block;  float: left; border:0; vertical-align:bottom;" width="600" /></a> 
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Any and all ideas are welcome please!

Comment: Hi @Sackling u want this as like http://tinkerbin.com/dyIhhJ9S

Comment: Hi, What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I see you added a white border top of 2px. That's exactly what I am trying to avoid?

Comment: Total shot in the dark: have you tried adding 'outline:none;' to the links as well?

Answer (score 1):

Just a question of order with attributes, it seems... Try like this, it's ok for me! ;)

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.anzie.com/"><img style="display:block;" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/ESSETIAL6_FALL_01.jpg" height="179" width="600" alt="Gold Rush" border="0" /></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.anzie.com/viewall_gold.php" target="_blank"><img border="0" alt="Shop Gold" height="25" src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php/http/gallery.mailchimp.com/5513172da1aa95c4b84fdedba/images/ESSETIAL6_FALL_02.1.jpg" style="display:block;" width="600" /></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I just ran this as well and took out all of your styles and attributes and it works.  Something within those two things is adding margin, border, or padding to your code.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the `width='600px'` from the `<td>`, so that it would take the width of the `img`